# Unaddressable access beyond top of stack

Tags: c++, lua

So I have a class to handle Lua scripts as part of a game. The following is the function to add a script to be run on every iteration along with many others running at the same time.

```
void create(string script, void *obj, map<string, Tools::lua_function> flist) // void *obj is a (Tools::LuaScript) casted to void*
```

It's stored in a map as followed:

```
map<string, pair<lua_State*, void*> > lua_states;
```

The create function just loads in the script and registers the function list, then stores the lua state on `lua_states[n]->first` and the pointer to the class which handles the script (derived from Tools::LuaScript class) on `void *obj` onto the `lua_states[n]->second`

Now I use this by calling `LuaHandler::run()` on every iteration which then loops through this map and calls `script->run(i->second.first);` because the `script` is the `void*` objected casted to the lua script class.

```
class LuaScript {
    public:
        virtual void run(lua_State*) = 0;
        virtual void render() = 0;
        virtual bool req_update() = 0;
};
```

To clarify, the `script->run()` calls the class relating to that script file which updates the script with required variables etc..., this is the whole point of this setup.

So this has worked fine, where I have successfully loaded three different scripts, but now, I created a new class, and added the script like this:

```
LuaHandler::i().create("script_file", (void*)(this), function_list);
```

Because the LuaHandler is a singleton, I can bind scripts from the constructor of the class to be binded. I did exactly the same thing in a previous class, I just copied it and changed the name of the class to create this new one.

However, when the time comes for this script to be loaded I get an `Illegal Instruction`, gdb didn't trace it very well so I used DrMemory and got this output:

http://pastebin.com/QuSqgxvp

So in the run method where I use

```
Tools::LuaScript* script = (Tools::LuaScript*)i->second.second;

    if(script->req_update()) { //LuaHandler:56
        ...
    }
```

This brings back some invalid pointer. I am calling `create()` just like I do in every class, but for some reason it fails in this particular case.

I apologise if this is hard to understand, it's tricky to explain, if needs be I can send the 2 files involved.

Tldr: Class derived from LuaScript (just allows the functions run(), render() and req_update() to be called abstractly) is 'binded' to a lua_State* using LuaHandler::i().create(), however when I loop through the binded scripts, and call any of these methods it fails. When it doesn't for other identical binded classes.

Comment: There's tons of possible causes, from trivial "using after object deleted" to less obvious cases with careless casts between void* and derived classes when multiple inheritance is involved. You'd better share minimal code that reproduces issue.

Comment: Well one of the classes I add inherits from two classes, whilst others don't, but I thought casting and storing them as void wouldn't matter as long as they all inherit from Tools::LuaScript it should be fine?

Comment: If they all inherit Tools:LuaScript, then store pointer to that base, do not cast through void*. When you do that, info about subclass position in hierarchy is lost, you will get wrong pointer when you will cast back from void* to derived class. See example: http://ideone.com/4vbWS0

Comment: So I changed the pointer to store directly to Tools::LuaScript but exactly the same happens, I still get that unaddressable access, and the program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I always end up answering my own question... Rookie mistake really, I created an instance of the class like this:

```
A c(mapp, renderer);
```

When I should have created a pointer

```
A *a = new A(app, renderer);
```

Because I created it at the end of a function where the instance got destroyed, hence the stored pointer becoming invalid.